# Is every $C^1$-domain which is homeomorphic to the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ Lipschitz equivalent to the unit ball?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, real-analysis

Suppose we have a domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which is homeomorrphic to the unit ball $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and such that $\partial \Omega$ is of class $C^1$ (technically, this means that for every point in the domain we can give a $C^1$-diffeomorphism to the half-space in dimension $n$).

A map $f\colon (X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ between metric spaces is said to be bi-Lipschitz if there is a constant $K>0$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{K} d_X(x_1,x_2) \leq d_Y(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \leq K d_X(x_1,x_2)$$
for all $x\in X$. The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are said to be Lipschitz equivalent if there is a surjective bi-Lipschitz map between them (any bi-Lipschitz map is necessarily injective).

*I wonder if in this case the domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz equivalent to the unit ball $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If true, is the condition $C^1$ necessary, sufficient?*

EDIT: My original question did not assume that the domain was homeomorphic to the ball. However, in this case it is clearly false, so I added this condition.

Comment: You need the domain to be homeomorphic to the ball if you want bi-Lipschitz equivalence, and simply connectedness is not enough if $n>2$. A small neighborhood of the unit sphere is simply connected but not homeomorphic to the ball.

Comment: But a small neighbourhood of the sphere would not be open if I understand your example?

Comment: I meant something like the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb R^n;0.9<|x|<1.1\}$, which is open, bounded, smooth and (if $n>2$) simply connected but not homeomorphic to the ball.

Comment: Yes I understood it now. So it's clearly false then.

Comment: Yes, but it is a more interesting problem whether a bounded $C^1$ domain which is homeomorphic to the ball is always bi-Lipschitz equivalent to it.

Comment: Shall I edit the question then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24079/discussion-between-mauricio-g-tec-and-joonas-ilmavirta).

Comment: In fact, more is true (except maybe in dimension 4): Your domain $\Omega$ is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to the unit ball. This follows from two facts: First, Whitney proved that each $C^k$-manifold is uniquely $C^\infty$-smoothable. Now combine this with the theorem (Smale et al, h-cobordism theorem) that two smooth structures on a closed ball are diffeomorphic. The situation (with your question) in dimension 4 is unclear and, I think, is an open problem.

Comment: One more thing to note: There is a concept of "Lipschitz manifolds". Sullivan proved (ca 1978) that, apart from dimension 4, each topological manifold admits a unique Lipschitz structure. Thus, for your question $C^1$-smoothness of the boundary is not needed, you just need (near) the boundary the domain to be locally bilipschitz to the round ball. This theorem fails in dimension 4, a result due to Donaldson and Sullivan (but, maybe, not if the manifold is a topological ball, that's unknown). When and if I have more time, I might convert my comments into a formal answer.